# S3 bucket files are not displaying after copying them over from my desktop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

`<Code>AccessDenied</Code>` Access Denied
`<RequestId>0A1692028D60A29E</RequestId>` lBXqqBepcm/rnJqfEhmHBEQilhKXwNERbIqE361p8LB55rgh+8TQCJc0XmKVPWnNeiIjKqwFGF8=

Comment: can you show the policy (json) that you have made to make it a public bucket? else you need set that up

Comment: I wasn't aware of this as i was following a tutorial where would i put this file and what should i put in it ? -cheers

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: It ended up being that I had to add the region I created the aws  bucket into my Django settings.py file with the following line: AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = “eu-west-2”. This is because it was trying to use the v2 auth mechanism which is not supported in my region (London).